# How to gsed multiple instance of a substring on the same line

Tags: awk, sed, tr

I have a 12k single-line file.

The file has zero \n characters in it.

It's all one line.

To facilitate further processing, I would like to insert an \n character after a certain string like 'foo', which I know I can do with gsed.

gsed only finds the first instance of foo and ignores the rest, because all foos are on the same 12k line.

For example:

`I am no foo so I pity the foo who tries to foo with me` <--- all in the same line

becomes:

```
 I am no foo

 so I pity the foo

 who tries to foo

 with me
```

I've looked at tr and awk but they don't quite do the job either.

Would be grateful for any clues.

Comment: Good that you have tried few things before posting on SO and you also stated same in your post too. Please do add those commands too in your post, cheers.

Comment: why not just `fmt file` ? Or with `sed s/foo/foo\n/g'` ?

Comment: *gsed only finds the first instance of foo and ignores the rest, because all foos are on the same 12k line.* are you sure? `sed 's/foo /foo\n/g'` works fine here.

Comment: I apologize - I don't know why this wasn't working for me last night, but it is today.  I'm sure it's some oversight on my part.  I've upvoted all the answers and would mark one of the comments as the correct one if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{gsub(/foo /,"&\n")} 1' Input_file
```